# Android scale view and re-layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

Sorry for the vague title. I really cannot present this question is few words. OK, let me describe what I want to achieve.

First, I have a vertical LinearLayout including two views. View A is visible and as big as possible(match parent). For View BI set it VIEW.GONE be default.

Then, triggered by something, View A will be scaled into half of its size. And View B will be shown by setting VIEW.VISIBLE. In order to make View A and View B have the same height, I assigned equal weight to them in xml. The following figures illustrate what I want to implement.

[figure](http://postimg.org/image/ei932labd/)

To scale View A, I make use of View.ScaleX(0.5f) and View.ScaleY(0.5f). Actually I implement the scale function in the animation way and set View B visibility in EndAnimation Callback.

But View A and View B cannot be shown properly. Half of each view is masked by unknown 'white block'.

And I also check the height-width of View A, before and after scaling, it does not change at all.

So is it possible to implement such feature?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to just give them equal weight and then hide and show B? B would then force A to shrink to it's assigned weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a scaleY animation on View A before displaying View B right? It is absolutely possible. I'm not sure what is the 'white-block' you're referring to. You should give some of your code if you want help debugging.

Otherwise, you should use an ObjectAnimator like this one :

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewA, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f);
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        viewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // You can display the view b with an animation
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewB, "alpha", 0f, 1f).start();

        // Remember to reset the scale factor since there will be a re-layout
        viewA.setScaleY(1.0f);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I want to scale View A to make room for displaying View B. But I found when I make scales on View A, it only affects how View A looks like, but not its exact size. So that when View B is set as visible, either it does not show (if I don't assign weight) or overlaps with View A (if I assign equal weight to them). I think the problem is that the scale function cannot affect view's exact size and how to re-layout their parent (let it know OK there is some room for View B). I will post my code and screenshots later. Thanks again.

Comment: Be careful about the scale animation, it is a 'draw only' animation : it doesn't care about the layout of the view. It affects the view at all times, meaning that if your set your scaleY at 50%, it will always display your view at 50% of its height, even after a layout. That's why you need to reset it at then end of the animation.
If you set your views with a 1:1 weight, they should have the exact same height when they're both visible and have a scaleY at 1.
Starting an animation that scale down viewA to 50% is an approximation because you know that you're always taking half of the ViewGroup.

Comment: A better way to animate them would be to set View B visible and launching a scaleY animation on view A and view B (scaling down view A and scaling up view B) before both of them are drawn (but after they're measured), with a getViewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener.